# Execution failed for task ':ui:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseKotlin'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, wireguard

Trying to build the android client for Wireguard (https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-android/about). I get the following error:

`Execution failed for task ':ui:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseKotlin'.`

after running:

`./gradlew assembleRelease`

Can't see anything relevant when using `--debug`, though I am a complete noob when it comes to Java/Android development. Other than the fact the repo is full of deprecated syntax, any ideas what could be the problem and how I can make this build?

Comment: Hi did you found the solution regarding this issue ?

Comment: @WaheedSabir No. I have been working on something else, so I have not had a chance to investigate further. I believe the issue is caused by Gradle needing a particular version, but updating Gradle did not fix it.